# Should NSURLProtocol::startLoading be asynch

Tags: iphone, webkit

I am subclassing NSURLProtocol.

Do get parallel performance, need I spawn the loading to a separate thread in startLoading, or is this handled for me by the URL loading framework (WebKit)?

Answer (score 0):

This is handled for you by the URL Loading System.

Answer (score 0):

Actually. I found that if your -startLoading method takes too much time (where too much can already be just loading a file from the filesystem), you get weird crashes with stacktraces which are completely unhelpful.

The only way to battle this is to dispatch_async yourself first thing and do any non-trivial work there.